# Hibernate: How to restore (bidirectional) parent relation on entity load programmatically?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, bidirectional

Child object is loaded by calling getChild() from Parent object (see example below). At this moment hibernate is aware about parent/child relation. How to use this information to restore bidirectional relation programmatically (say to set parent field in child)?

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Child child;

    public Child getChild(){
        return child;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Transient
    private Object parent;

    public Object getParent(){
        return parent;
    }
}
```

Motivation: child may be referenced from different classes, but at runtime there is only one parent object allowed. Using "mappedby" would result in multiple "inverse"-fields in Child class. This is not desired, since only one parent object may exist at runtime. The type of parent object is not crucial for the usecase.

Answer (score 0):

using mappedBy property in @OneToOne
set the property mappedBy = "class ref";

```
 @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 private Child child;
```

Comment: Class Child comes from a library. This library may be referenced from diverse Projects. Hence, the Parent class is not visible to Child. The suggested solution mith "mappedBy" requires parent-Field to be strongly typed. But this is in general not possible, because Child is not aware of Parent class.

Comment: My intention is to "recreate" the parent object (on child load) from unidirectional relation. I expected to achive this by implementing something like custom EntityTuplizer, but hibernate doesn't expose any information about the parent while instantiating the child object. Is there any way to get the reference to parent object while loading the child?

Comment: I think, this is very strange, that Hibernate or JPA in general don't allow bidirectional relations between  Projects/Libraries. I don't see any principal limitation to do this either on the Java side or database.